# __del__ at program end

Tags: python

Suppose there is a program with a couple of objects living in it at runtime.

Is the __del__ method of each object called when the programs ends?

If yes I could for example do something like this:

```
class Client:
  __del__( self ):
    disconnect_from_server()
```

Answer (score 7):

There are many [potential difficulties](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) associated with using `__del__`.
Usually, it is not necessary, or the best idea to define it yourself.

Instead, if you want an object that cleans up after itself upon exit or an exception, use a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

**per Carl's comment:**

```
class Client:
    def __exit__(self,ext_type,exc_value,traceback):
        self.disconnect_from_server()

with Client() as c:
    ...
```

**original answer:**

```
import contextlib

class Client:
    ...

@contextlib.contextmanager
def make_client():
    c=Client()
    yield c
    c.disconnect_from_server()

with make_client() as c:
    ...
```

Comment: Also, you can define methods to accomplish the same: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers

Answer (score 6):

I second the general idea of using context managers and the `with` statement instead of relying on `__del__` (for much the same reasons one prefers try/finally to finalizer methods in Java, plus one: in Python, the presence of `__del__` methods can make cyclic garbage uncollectable).

However, given that the goal is to have "an object that cleans up after itself upon exit or an exception", the implementation by @~unutbu is *not* correct:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def make_client():
    c=Client()
    yield c
    c.disconnect_from_server()

with make_client() as c:
    ...
```

If an exception is raised in the `...` part, `disconnect_from_server_` does **not** get called (since the exception propagates through `make_client`, being uncaught there, and therefore terminates it while it's waiting at the `yield`).

The fix is simple:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def make_client():
    c=Client()
    try: yield c
    finally: c.disconnect_from_server()
```

Essentially, the `with` statement lets you *almost* forget about the good old try/finally statement... **except** when you're writing context managers with `contextlib`, and then it's really important to remember it!-)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [with-statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to make cleanup explicit.
With circular references `__del__` is not called:

```
class Foo:
  def __del__(self):
    self.p = None
    print "deleting foo"

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.p = b
b.p = a
```

prints nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Python interpreter tidies up at shutdown, including calling the `__del__` method of every object (except objects that are part of a reference cycle).

Although, as others have pointed out, `__del__` methods are very fragile and should be used with caution.